# Silverlight application does not shows Message Box

Tags: silverlight, messagebox

I am making web application in silverlight. In that application i have shown message box as

```
MessageBox.Show("Hello");
```

whenever i am running application in Visual Studio,it shows the message box correctly. But whenever i am deploying my application and trying to access, it does not shows message box. Now whether i have to write client side code to display message or any other logic. Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where you have defined this message box??

Comment: In what browsers does this happen?  IE? Chrome? Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're doing that on the server, not the client.
That won't work.

You need to display the message in the Silverlight or Javascript client code.